# Get Microsoft GRAPH access token from Nodejs script

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

This question builds on [How to get Microsoft Graph API Access token from Node Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613628/how-to-get-microsoft-graph-api-access-token-from-node-script), however, as a first-time user of, I don't have the required reputation for commenting on the accepted answer in that thread.

The thing is, I tried to implement the approach suggested by the accepted answer, but somewhere it goes wrong. The below code is part of an async function, and I can already tell you that the `ONEDRIVE_TENANT_URI is` of the format `XXX.onmicrosoft.com`.

```
const endpoint = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.ONEDRIVE_TENTANT_URI}/oauth2/token`;
const requestParams = {
  grant_type: "client_credentials",
  client_id: process.env.ONEDRIVE_APP_ID,
  client_secret: process.env.ONEDRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  resource: "https://graph.windows.net"
};

const authResponse = await request.post({
  url: endpoint,
  form: requestParams
});
```

`authResponse` gets, as its body, just a string with the requestParams as defined above filled out.

If I submit the post request via Postman, with the same parameters as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, I DO get an `access_token` in the response body.

So... What do I do wrong? Maybe - but I don't think so - it's because this function is invoked by a (for testing purposes) POSTMAN GET request with a json-formatted body?

Comment: There isn't a lot to go on here. Please edit your question and add some additional code, specifically where you're setting `requestParams`. It also isn't clear how or where you registered your application.

Comment: Added some code as per your request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the sample [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-apponlytoken-rest-sample). And fill in the credentials in `config.js`. You can find them from Azure portal.
[image]

This is the code to get access token.

```
auth.getAccessToken = function () {
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  // These are the parameters necessary for the OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow.
  // For more information, see Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn645543.aspx).
  var requestParams = {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: config.clientId,
    client_secret: config.clientSecret,
    resource: 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
  };

  // Make a request to the token issuing endpoint.
  request.post({ url: config.tokenEndpoint, form: requestParams }, function (err, response, body) {
    var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(parsedBody);
    if (err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    } else if (parsedBody.error) {
      deferred.reject(parsedBody.error_description);
    } else {
      // If successful, return the access token.
      deferred.resolve(parsedBody.access_token);
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

You will get the access token successfully.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I know it should work - but it doesn't. I follow the same example/tutorial, and it does work in Postman as a direct POST request, but it seems to fail when it's part of a larger stream of functions initiated by a GET request... although I don't think that should present a problem...

I also changed graph.windows.net to graph.microsoft.com, to no avail.

Comment: Did you make any change of the sample?

Comment: There is no error message, it just returns a useless response with a lot of data, but not the data that you expect. As mentioned, it has a 'body', but its value is just the query string of the requestParams

Comment: Please modify your request code to these code to have a try. request.post({ url: config.tokenEndpoint, form: requestParams }, function (err, response, body) {
    var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
 console.log(parsedBody);
    if (err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    } else if (parsedBody.error) {
      deferred.reject(parsedBody.error_description);
    } else {
      // If successful, return the access token.
      deferred.resolve(parsedBody.access_token);
    }
  });

Comment: request.post({ url: endpoint, form: requestParams },function(err,response,body){
 console.log(body);
}
 ) Try this one and see if it works.

Comment: That works! Why? Is there an issue with the request module in combination with await? Does it not support ES6 fat arrow functionality?

Comment: @Fronzie Just like Marc said, request doesn't natively support promises. And you can find more details here. https://github.com/request/request#promises--asyncawait

Answer (score 0):

You've got two issues going on.

The first isn't an issue *yet*, but it will be once you try to call Microsoft Graph. The `resource` should be `graph.microsoft.net`, *not* `graph.windows.net`. The `graph.windows.net` refers to the legacy Azure AD Graph API, not Microsoft Graph.

The other issue, which is the root cause of this error, is `await request.post`. Request doesn't natively support promises. From the Request the [documentation](https://github.com/request/request#promises--asyncawait):

> `request` supports both streaming and callback interfaces natively. If you'd like `request` to return a Promise instead, you can use an alternative interface wrapper for `request`. These wrappers can be useful if you prefer to work with Promises, or if you'd like to use `async`/`await` in ES2017.
>
> Several alternative interfaces are provided by the request team, including:
>
> - [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise) (uses [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) Promises)
> - [`request-promise-native`](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) (uses native Promises)
> - [`request-promise-any`](https://github.com/request/request-promise-any) (uses [any-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/any-promise) Promises)