# Creating a AD Security group in Azure AD in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create a security group in my azure AD directory and add b2c user (who has logged in) to that group.

`msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret('72a3198b-', '-FvUZZ4G', tenantId, { tokenAudience: 'graph' }, function (err, credentials, subscriptions) {
    if (err) console.log("error: " + err);
    else {
        console.log(util.inspect(credentials));
    }
    var client = new graphRbacManagementClient(credentials, tenantId);
    client.groups.list({}, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log('Could not list groups', err)
        }
        else {
            console.log("result: " + result);
        }
    })`

I have enabled the API permission on Azure....

[image: Azure AD SP permissions]

Although I authenticate using my SP successfully, i get a 403 back in response whether I try to create a new group or list the existing groups etc.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

UPDATE: I changed the code and used `msRestAzure.loginWithUsernamePassword` instead. The username and password I used was for a user with Admin privilege. After the change, the code worked and created/Listed the group. So my guess is, the SP needs some sort of a Access/API permission that I haven't enabled. I just don't know what..

Comment: perhaps [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-dotnetcore-webapi-roles-groups) would be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`graphRbacManagementClient`](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/javascript/azure-graph/5.0.0/index.html) is not supported to call MS graph api. It is used for  Azure AD Graph API.

Here is a [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node) that you can follow. It uses microsoft-graph-client for making calls to Microsoft Graph.

Get access token using client credentials flow:

```
const request = require("request");

const endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[Tenant]/oauth2/v2.0/token";
const requestParams = {
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    client_id: "[ApplicationID]",
    client_secret: "[Key]",
    scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
};

request.post({ url:endpoint, form: requestParams }, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Body=" + body);
        let parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);         
        if (parsedBody.error_description) {
            console.log("Error=" + parsedBody.error_description);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Access Token=" + parsedBody.access_token);
        }
    }
});
```

Call MS Graph API:

```
// list groups
function testListGroupGraphAPI(accessToken) {
    request.get({
        url:"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups",
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
        }
    }, function(err, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
}

// create group    
function testCreateGroupGraphAPI(accessToken) {
    request.post({
        url:"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups",
        headers: {
           "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
        },
        json: {
            "description": "Self help community for library",
            "displayName": "Library Assist",
            "groupTypes": [
                "Unified"
            ],
            "mailEnabled": true,
            "mailNickname": "library",
            "securityEnabled": false
            }
    }, function(err, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
}
```

For more details, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55380279/13308381).

---

The permissions of **Azure AD Graph** are here:

[image]

Comment: As per my post, I am trying to create a Group in my Azure AD Directory using a service principle. I am NOT trying to get any info about the user etc. What sdk should I use? Any sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: @SeanD You could use access token to call graph api without user info. I update my answer to the sample code.

Comment: @SeanD add this permission(Navigate to Azure Active Directory Graph-> Application-> Directory.ReadWrite.All). You could call api with `graphRbacManagementClient`

Comment: As you see from my screenshot, Directory.ReadWrite.All is added. Still getting 403. !@#$

Comment: @SeanD I mean the permission of **Azure Active Directory Graph**, not Microsoft Graph. Azure Active Directory Graph is the older of MS Graph. If you still want to use MS Graph, the code in my answer will help.