# Node.js back-end application on Firebase to access Azure Active Directory users

Tags: node.js, firebase, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a Node.js back which currently is running on Firebase in the form of [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). Except for that, I also have an Azure Active Directory with some users that I have invited

[image]

So, I want to be able to access them from the Node.js get a list of their emails and names. From what I understood, I can achieve that by making a reference to [Microsoft's Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) and more specifically to their [Users API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#get-users--). As every request to Azure AD needs to be OAuth2 authenticated, I was wondering what is the best way of achieving that in my situation. What client flow do I need to implement? I am currently focused on the one which is based on [client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/dn645543(v=azure.100)).

Thanks in advance and whatever general suggestion are more than welcome!

Comment: Have you tried using Microsoft Graph API + authorization code flow? I think this is more suitable for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55380279/13308381) gets Access token and calls Microsoft Graph API using node.js.

The [user API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#get-users--) of Azure Active Directory Graph API is no longer updating. This [MS graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is newer.

Get access token using client credentials flow:

```
const request = require("request");

const endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[Tenant]/oauth2/v2.0/token";
const requestParams = {
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    client_id: "[ApplicationID]",
    client_secret: "[Key]",
    scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
};

request.post({ url:endpoint, form: requestParams }, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Body=" + body);
        let parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);         
        if (parsedBody.error_description) {
            console.log("Error=" + parsedBody.error_description);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Access Token=" + parsedBody.access_token);
        }
    }
});
```

Call MS Graph API:

```
function testListGroupGraphAPI(accessToken) {
    request.get({
        url:"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users",
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
        }
    }, function(err, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
}
```